# Why does killing a process gets printed in console

Tags: shell-script, shell, kill, background-process

I have about 100 server processes running in background. Whenever I kill them, I get 100 messages (one for each server) that the corresponding pid was killed.

For example:

```
./kill_script.sh: line 196: 1996 Killed         myserver 1
./kill_script.sh: line 196: 1997 Killed         myserver 2

# and so on till myserver 100
```

I do not want these messages to get printed. In fact, until a few hours ago, these were not getting printed. I have no clue why are these getting printed now.

Edit: If that matters, I use KILL -9 to kill these processes. But so was I doing earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this (really) because the shell's developers decided it would be helpful.  You can make it quiet(er):

- [How to suppress Terminated message after killing in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash)

The relevant code in bash looks like this:

```
              else if (IS_FOREGROUND (job))
                {
#if !defined (DONT_REPORT_SIGPIPE)
                  if (termsig && WIFSIGNALED (s) && termsig != SIGINT)
#else
                  if (termsig && WIFSIGNALED (s) && termsig != SIGINT && termsig != SIGPIPE)
#endif
                    { 
                      fprintf (stderr, "%s", j_strsignal (termsig));

                      if (WIFCORED (s))
                        fprintf (stderr, _(" (core dumped)"));

                      fprintf (stderr, "\n");
                    }
                }
```

which (the `IS_FOREGROUND`) suggests that you're seeing the message when you don't put your script in the background.

Comment: But how come I was not facing this issue until a few hours ago. I have not changed a single line in my script.

Comment: Not seeing your script: you may have a trap instruction which sometimes catches the signal, sometimes not depending on what your servers are doing.

Comment: @SonuMishra This message is only printed with SIGKILL (`kill -9`), and it can not be trapped.

Comment: The bash source says it's printed if the jobs are running in the foreground.  In a quick read, I don't see it if the jobs were backgrounded.

Comment: Exactly, my jobs are running in background